# Groupby count in pandas of two categorical column - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have df as shown below.

df

```
ID      Type        Status       Age
1       2           P            23
2       1           P            28
3       1           F            33
4       3           P            48
5       1           F            23
6       2           P            28
7       2           F            23
8       3           P            38
```

From the above I would like to perform groupby count of `Status` based on `Type`

Expected output:

```
Type     Status       Frequency
1        F            2
1        P            1
2        F            1
2        P            2
3        F            0
3        P            2
```

I tried below code

```
df.groupby('Type').agg('Status': 'size').\
        sort_values(ascending = False).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Type, df.Status)
Out[268]: 
Status  F  P
Type        
1       2  1
2       1  2
3       0  2
```

---

```
pd.crosstab(df.Type, df.Status).stack().reset_index(name = 'freq')
Out[273]: 
   Type Status  freq
0     1      F     2
1     1      P     1
2     2      F     1
3     2      P     2
4     3      F     0
5     3      P     2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `value_counts`:

```
df.groupby('Type').Status.value_counts().reset_index(name='Frequency')
```

Output:

```
   Type Status  Frequency
0     1      F          2
1     1      P          1
2     2      P          2
3     2      F          1
4     3      P          2
```

Or replace `reset_index` with `unstack` to get the missing groups:

```
df.groupby('Type').Status.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Status  F  P
Type        
1       2  1
2       1  2
3       0  2
```

**Note**: `df.groupby('Type').Status.value_counts()` is somewhat equivalent to `df.groupby(['Type,'Status']).size()`.